# Chai expect property to exist, but not contain specific string

Tags: javascript, chai

I would like to test that a function returns an array of objects that have a property 'src' but value of 'src' does not contain the string "sample".

```
var images = [
    {
        id: 11111,
        src: 'images/sample-red_dress.jpg',
        position: 1
    },
    {
        id: 21111,
        src: 'images/front-red_dress.jpg',
        position: 2
    },
    {
        id: 21112,
        src: 'images/back-red_dress.jpg',
        position: 3
    }
];

var result = removeSampleImages(images);

expect(result).to.all.have.property('src').and.to.not.contain("sample");
```

Unfortunately this test still passes when the results array contains an object whose src property contains 'sample'.

Comment: What does `removeSampleImages()` look like?

Comment: It sounds like you're checking whether any of the items are `"sample"` rather than if any of the items have a `src` property set to `"sample"`. You'll need to loop through the results, either with a Chai helper or just an `expect(result.every(it => src.indexOf('sample') === -1))`.

Comment: @br3w5 It doesn't matter. For the sake of this test let's say that the function is written incorrectly and it just returns what ever it is passed.

Comment: @cormickjbrowne it does matter because how `result` looks will affect how you assert against it. Right now your logic right now reads like 'check that objects have a property 'src' and check that the same objects do not contain the text 'sample'` rather than checking that `src` does not include/contain the text. The tests pass because "sample" is undefined if you just check against the object - you need to check the value against the `src` key

Comment: @br3w5 I just mean that it doesn't matter how the function is written because I want to know how to write the test not the function. I ended up writting this:

expect(result.every(function (image) { return image.src.indexOf('sample') === -1; })).to.be.true;

Comment: @cormickjbrowne ok glad you got it figured out